# How to avoid code duplication with similar Django model methods?

Tags: django, methods, code-duplication

The following model contains the two almost identical functions `list_ancestors` and `list_descendants`. What would be a good way to write this code only once?

```
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    parents = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False)

    def list_parents(self):
        return self.parents.all()

    def list_children(self):
        return Node.objects.filter(parents=self.id)

    def list_ancestors(self):
        parents = self.list_parents()
        ancestors = set(parents)
        for p in parents:
            ancestors |= set(p.list_ancestors())  # set union
        return list(ancestors)

    def list_descendants(self):
        children = self.list_children()
        descendants = set(children)
        for c in children:
            descendants |= set(c.list_descendants())  # set union
        return list(descendants)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

EDIT: The solution derived from the answers below:

```
def list_withindirect(self, arg):
    direct = getattr(self, arg)()
    withindirect = set(direct)
    for d in direct:
         withindirect |= set(d.list_withindirect(arg))
    return list(withindirect)

def list_ancestors(self):
     return self.list_withindirect('list_parents')

def list_descendants(self):
     return self.list_withindirect('list_children')
```

Comment: @Sayse: I don't understand your question. Ancestors are a generalization of parents, so `list_ancestors` uses `list_parents`. Descendants are a generalization of children, so `list_descendants` uses `list_children`.

Comment: `list_ancestors` first gets the parents, and then recursively gets the ancestors of the parents. `list_descendants` first gets the children, and then recursively gets the descendants of the children. As these two similar functions I try to unify are recursive, my "solution" `list_withindirect` is recursive as well.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a string and call getattr on the object to get the callable function.

```
def list_withindirect(self, fn1):
    direct = getattr(self, fn1)()
    withindirect = set(direct)
    for d in direct:
         withindirect |= set(d.list_withindirect(fn1))

    return list(withindirect)

def list_ancestors(self):
     return self.list_withindirect('list_parents')
```

Comment: That does not work. When I try to use `list_ancestors`, I get some `ImportError` and `TypeError: list_withindirect() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. I have no idea what you are trying to do with `getattr` BTW.

Comment: @Watchduck  remove the second `self` in the last line

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: @schwobaseggl: (faceplam).  Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the issue in **bound** and **unbound** methods problem.

When you're initially pass `self.list_parents` to `self.list_withindirect(list_direct)` everything is OK.

But when you're recursively pass the same! `self.list_parents` to `d.list_withindirect` (i.e. to descendants), you're accidentally populate your `direct` variable with parents of the topmost caller object, instead of `d`.

For example, it may be resolved using `getattr`, like it was answered by **2ps** *(upd: the error in his original code was found in comments there)*.

Comment: `d.list_direct` leads to `AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'list_direct'`.

Comment: Sure. So, I wouldn't try to find wo getaatr solution (I'm sure it's possible), since you've already got an answer. I'm leaving only the reasons explanation of the original issue in my post.